# How do I change the background selection color for a jface table

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

In a elipse-rcp application I am setting the background color for a row in a jface table but I don't want the selection to change this color. I want to be able to specify the color change for a selected row.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg41815.html), for  `JFace Viewers` (`ListViewer`, `Table`, `Tree`) by means of using `EraseItem` and `MeasureItem` events

General principle detailed in the article "[Custom Drawing Table and Tree Items](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html)"

> `SWT.EraseItem`: allows a client to custom draw a cell's background and/or selection, and to influence whether the cell's foreground should be drawn

[image]

Comment: Thanks VonC. Using the code from the above example I was able to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

```
table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
        if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) == 0) return; /// item not selected

        Table table =(Table)event.widget;
        TableItem item =(TableItem)event.item;
        int clientWidth = table.getClientArea().width;

        GC gc = event.gc;               
        Color oldForeground = gc.getForeground();
        Color oldBackground = gc.getBackground();

        gc.setBackground(colorBackground);
        gc.setForeground(colorForeground);              
        gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, clientWidth, event.height);

        gc.setForeground(oldForeground);
        gc.setBackground(oldBackground);
        event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
    }
});
```

Comment: @ks: thank you for that feedback. +1. You could choose your own post as the official answer if you want