# SWT TableCombo disable highlighting of selected item

Tags: java, swt, highlighting

I am using [TableCombo](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) and when I push the dropdown button, the list of all items is shown. I would like to achieve that currently selected row is not highlighted in this list (because I use different background colors depending on type of item and the highlight hides the background color of selected item). I have tried creating the table with `SWT.NO_FOCUS` and `SWT.HIDE_SELECTION` flags, but it did not remove the highlight. Any ideas?

I have tried to find out something like highlighter in swing, but I haven't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006924/windows-7-swt-table-selected-row-highlight-color), which pretty much answers my question. For `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` highlighting is taken care of by OS automatically - see `Table.CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT(NMLVCUSTOMDRAW nmcd, int wParam, int lParam)` on Win32.

However this behavior can be modified by style constants. Correct solution for me was using `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` (whole row can be selected) and `SWT.NO_FOCUS` (dark blue highlight is not used) and `SWT.HIDE_SELECTION` (hides default gray background color for selected item) flags together.

Sadly, the `HIDE_SELECTION` flag is not supported by SWT `Tree`.

Comment: Great! No wait.. it does not seem to work for `Table`/`TableViewer`s neither.. U_U

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/916866/1329340), one could disable the event passed on to `SWT.EraseItem`:

```
table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {   
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
    }
});
```

`table` is the SWT table I get from my JFace `TableViewer`. Not sure about the `TableCombo` API.