# How to keep custom colors in SWT cells?

Tags: java, swt

I made a class that extends from `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` to customize the cell's content. Then I override the method paint, so only a column will be green.

```
paint(Event event, Object element) {
   TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
   Color color = SWTResourceManager.getColor(0, 204, 0);
   item.setBackground(7, color);
}
```

but when the row is selected or mouse hovers over, the custom color is not showed.

Maybe it's important to say that cell is green only when it meets some validations, so it is important for my user. The problem is when they only get one result in table and then they select the only row and think that the result is "normal".

Comment: So what you actually want is to "override" the default highlight color of a cell? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097428/swt-tablecombo-disable-highlighting-of-selected-item).

Comment: Yes, I don't know if there is a way to make the highlight simply transparent?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted.

Comment: It didn't work for me, tried to search other solution, unsuccessfully.